# Arduino virtualbox serial port

Tags: arduino, serial-port, virtualbox

I want programming arduino leonardo on kali linux virtualbox guest under windows 8.1 host. I know that Arduino IDE is developed in java so it's not dependent on any operating system, but reason why i want to use kali is due to some of its programs (SET toolkit, Kautilya).

First i checked serial port on my host WIN 8.1 OS. (Arduino Leonardo COM3)

[image]

Then in virtualbox i changed serial settings for my kali virtual mashine. As I noticed:

**Port Number** presents port number on virtual mashine (kali) and that will be COM1 port ie. /dev/ttyS0

**Port/File Path** presents port number on host (win8) OS and that is COM3:

[image]

After these settings i boot virtual mashine and tried to upload simple sketch on arduino leonardo. The result in Adruino IDE is "Done uploading" but nothing happens.

[image]

I tried using ino via command line but result is error.

```
 ino upload -p /dev/ttyS0
```

[image]

Does someone perhaps know a solution?

Comment: I experienced some issues with the serial port driver in VB... Also because there are problems if the USB cable is disconnected from the PC while the virtual machine is running. If possible, I suggest you to use the USB virtualbox driver instead of the serial one: Remove the serial port configuration, then boot the machine and select it like you would do for any USB peripheral. If you can't, I found that using `\\.\comX` instead of `COMX:` fixes some problems, so try with `\\.\com3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arduino Leonardo use two serial COM ports. The first one, the one that you are seeing is used for data transmission between the Arduino and your Computer, i.e., used to send data from sensors read by your Arduino to your computer. There is another serial COM that is used to program the Arduino. That serial COM is only available and visible when you are programming the device. This COM talks to the bootloader of your Arduino.

You may create a USB filter in VirtualBox so as soon as you plug in your Arduino (COM1) it will be seen by your GUEST OS. I think that the vendor ID and the Product ID of the USB Device will depend of the bootloader of your Arduino, but you may create a filter without this parameters so EVERY new USB device connected to your HOST OS will be seen by your GUEST OS. So this will manage your two serial COM ports in order.